# Favorite non-constructive proofs.

Tags: soft-question, alternative-proof, big-list

There are many results for which a constructive proof exists but is not as nice as the non-constructive proof. For example the explicit construction of a continuous nowhere-differentiable function is rather technical compared to the proof of existence invoking the Baire category theorem.

What are your favorite non-constructive proofs or methods?

Comment: The Claude Shannon Capacity Theorem of Information Theory: There exist codes that get arbitrarily close to capacity (due to a randomization argument) but it is very hard to construct one.  In particular, it is hard to find one with an easy coding/decoding rule.

Comment: I think that the existence of normal numbers satisfies this. The constructive proof required an odd construction as well as quite a bit of work to show that the constructed number is normal, but the proof that nearly all reals are normal is far prettier.

Comment: I think this is a great question, but not appropriate for this site - it's simply too broad. (That said, I'll mention the proof that [each Chomp game is determined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomp#Winning_the_game), which is one-long line and reveals no information about the winning strategy whatsoever!)

Comment: Related: ["Strange" proofs of existence theorems](https://mathoverflow.net/q/312439/15780) *AND* [Examples of ubiquitous objects that are hard to find?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/153141/15780)

Answer (score 5):

I have always liked:

Claim:  There exist  irrational numbers $\alpha,\beta$, possibly equal, such that $\alpha^{\beta}$ is rational.

Pf:   Consider $\sqrt 2 ^{\sqrt 2}$.  If it is rational then we are done.  If it is irrational, then call it $\alpha$ and consider $\alpha^{\sqrt 2}=2$.  And we are done.

Comment: @MatthewDaly  It's truly a great argument.  Especially when you compare it to the proof that $\sqrt 2^{\sqrt 2}$ is in fact irrational.

Comment: This one is nice but it isn't really any simpler than a constructive proof. $\sqrt{2}^{\log_2(9)}=3$ is an easy example. Everyone knows that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, and $\log_2{9}$ is irrational because $2^a$ and $9^b$ are different mod 2.

Answer (score 3):

Strategy Stealing is another classic example that applies to a number of turn-based games. It shows that either the first player always wins or that the game will end in a tie, assuming perfect play from both sides. The proofs never actually exhibit the strategies in question.

For example take Tic Tac Toe (on an arbitrarily large board of size $n\times n$). Suppose player 2  has a winning strategy $S$, regardless of player 1's first move. Then we make a number of observations:

1) Regardless of where player 1 plays the first $X$, player 2 supposidly has a winning strategy, which is a function of the position of the first $X$.

2) There is never a disadvantage to having one of your pieces already on the board, meaning that if player 1 already has an $X$ on a given square, then that cannot the worse than not having an $X$ on that square.

3) By 1), player 1 can adopt player 2's strategy by randomly placing an $X$, and then after player 2 responds with their strategy $S$, player 1 applies $S$ to player 2's response, with $X$ and $O$ switched. If $S$ ever calls to play on the first $X$ that player 1 had to place, then player 1 can make a random move by 2).

So player 2 could not possibly have a winning strategy $S$, which means either player 1 always wins or the game always ends in a tie.

Answer (score 2):

Shout out for Brouwer's Fixed Point theorem, if only because Brouwer's other major claim to fame is being such a strict constructivist.